# Is secure having MySQL in separate document? Because of include function

Tags: php, mysql, security

I learned (from internet tutorials) to create separate file, like **mysql.php**, with password and username.

```
$dbserver = "localhost";
$dbname = "";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "";

$db = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbheslo);
mysql_select_db($dbnazev, $db);
```

And whenever I would need connect to mysql, I would use in my code **include "mysql.php"**.

But doesn't it mean, that anybody in the internet can include this file to his script and get into my database?

BTW: My hosting is not using localhost, it's using **mysql87.example.com**... .

Comment: PSA: Stop using `mysql_connect` etc. It's deprecated, and won't be in PHP proper for much longer (if it hasn't already been moved out into PECL; i haven't kept track).

Comment: Nope. Try open that file with a Web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation I can say to that it IS safe to use it that way (not my way, i like classes) and this is why:

When you start your web server there is php server started also (mod_php, php-fpm, php-cgi or other). This php server exclude from document, that will be shown to any other person that includes it thru web server.

This means that code

```
<!-- SOME CODE HERE -->
<?php require('mysql.php'); ?>
<!-- SOME CODE HERE ALSO -->
```

will be rewrited to

```
<!-- SOME CODE HERE -->

<!-- SOME CODE HERE ALSO -->
```

So anyone who includes this file will not see php code.

This means that it is safe to use it like this. But i recommend to secure direct access to such kind of files.

### index.php

```
<?php

define ('MY_CUSTOM_CONSTANT', 42);

require('mysql.php');
// Other code
```

### mysql.php

```
<?php
defined('MY_CUSTOM_CONSTANT') or die('You cannot access to this file directly');
```

In this case even if they include or just call this file from web - they will just get text message and code will not be executed in this case

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can browse to your script, and it'll connect to the database, but the script will then immediately end. Assuming you aren't messing around with form or cookie variables in your `mysql.php` script, the would-be attacker is left with no way to run a query, so your database is safe.